# Kingswaysoft Metadata Fields Return Null

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

Is there a bug in Kingwaysoft where some metadata fields return `null`? I have a large project downloading all account fields and metadata, and they all work except for `owneridtype` and a few others. Fields like `customertypecodename` come over fine, and I've verified that `owneridtype` is mapped the same as all others. My source is a fetchxml query.

I'm seeing the problem for these account fields, as well as for `regardingobjecttypecode` on the `activitypointer` entity:

`owneridtype`

`donotsendmarketingmaterialname`

`isprivatename`

`masteraccountidname`

`owneridtype`

Here is my query, minus custom fields. I can add those if needed.

```
<fetch mapping='logical'>
    <entity name='account'>
        <attribute name='accountcategorycode'/>
        <attribute name='accountcategorycodename'/>
        <attribute name='accountclassificationcode'/>
        <attribute name='accountclassificationcodename'/>
        <attribute name='accountid'/>
        <attribute name='accountnumber'/>
        <attribute name='accountratingcode'/>
        <attribute name='accountratingcodename'/>
        <attribute name='address1_addressid'/>
        <attribute name='address1_addresstypecode'/>
        <attribute name='address1_addresstypecodename'/>
        <attribute name='address1_city'/>
        <attribute name='address1_composite'/>
        <attribute name='address1_country'/>
        <attribute name='address1_county'/>
        <attribute name='address1_fax'/>
        <attribute name='address1_freighttermscode'/>
        <attribute name='address1_freighttermscodename'/>
        <attribute name='address1_latitude'/>
        <attribute name='address1_line1'/>
        <attribute name='address1_line2'/>
        <attribute name='address1_line3'/>
        <attribute name='address1_longitude'/>
        <attribute name='address1_name'/>
        <attribute name='address1_postalcode'/>
        <attribute name='address1_postofficebox'/>
        <attribute name='address1_primarycontactname'/>
        <attribute name='address1_shippingmethodcode'/>
        <attribute name='address1_shippingmethodcodename'/>
        <attribute name='address1_stateorprovince'/>
        <attribute name='address1_telephone1'/>
        <attribute name='address1_telephone2'/>
        <attribute name='address1_telephone3'/>
        <attribute name='address1_upszone'/>
        <attribute name='address1_utcoffset'/>
        <attribute name='address2_addressid'/>
        <attribute name='address2_addresstypecode'/>
        <attribute name='address2_addresstypecodename'/>
        <attribute name='address2_city'/>
        <attribute name='address2_composite'/>
        <attribute name='address2_country'/>
        <attribute name='address2_county'/>
        <attribute name='address2_fax'/>
        <attribute name='address2_freighttermscode'/>
        <attribute name='address2_freighttermscodename'/>
        <attribute name='address2_latitude'/>
        <attribute name='address2_line1'/>
        <attribute name='address2_line2'/>
        <attribute name='address2_line3'/>
        <attribute name='address2_longitude'/>
        <attribute name='address2_name'/>
        <attribute name='address2_postalcode'/>
        <attribute name='address2_postofficebox'/>
        <attribute name='address2_primarycontactname'/>
        <attribute name='address2_shippingmethodcode'/>
        <attribute name='address2_shippingmethodcodename'/>
        <attribute name='address2_stateorprovince'/>
        <attribute name='address2_telephone1'/>
        <attribute name='address2_telephone2'/>
        <attribute name='address2_telephone3'/>
        <attribute name='address2_upszone'/>
        <attribute name='address2_utcoffset'/>
        <attribute name='adx_createdbyipaddress'/>
        <attribute name='adx_createdbyusername'/>
        <attribute name='adx_modifiedbyipaddress'/>
        <attribute name='adx_modifiedbyusername'/>
        <attribute name='aging30'/>
        <attribute name='aging30_base'/>
        <attribute name='aging60'/>
        <attribute name='aging60_base'/>
        <attribute name='aging90'/>
        <attribute name='aging90_base'/>
        <attribute name='businesstypecode'/>
        <attribute name='businesstypecodename'/>
        <attribute name='cdi_allowtextmessages'/>
        <attribute name='cdi_allowtextmessagesname'/>
        <attribute name='CFBcrmconsulting'/>
        <attribute name='CFBcrmconsultingname'/>
        <attribute name='CFBcrmelementsoutlook'/>
        <attribute name='CFBcrmelementsoutlookname'/>
        <attribute name='CFBcrmelementsrealestate'/>
        <attribute name='CFBcrmelementsrealestatename'/>
        <attribute name='CFBcrmlicenses'/>
        <attribute name='CFBcrmlicensesname'/>
        <attribute name='CFPEmailSoftware'/>
        <attribute name='CFPEmailSoftwarename'/>
        <attribute name='CFPnumberofemployeesrange'/>
        <attribute name='CFPnumberofemployeesrangename'/>
        <attribute name='CFProle'/>
        <attribute name='CFProlename'/>
        <attribute name='CFPSalesForceSoftware'/>
        <attribute name='CFPSalesForceSoftwarename'/>
        <attribute name='createdby'/>
        <attribute name='createdbyexternalparty'/>
        <attribute name='createdbyexternalpartyname'/>
        <attribute name='createdbyexternalpartyyominame'/>
        <attribute name='createdbyname'/>
        <attribute name='createdbyyominame'/>
        <attribute name='createdon'/>
        <attribute name='createdonbehalfby'/>
        <attribute name='createdonbehalfbyname'/>
        <attribute name='createdonbehalfbyyominame'/>
        <attribute name='creditlimit'/>
        <attribute name='creditlimit_base'/>
        <attribute name='creditonhold'/>
        <attribute name='creditonholdname'/>
        <attribute name='customersizecode'/>
        <attribute name='customersizecodename'/>
        <attribute name='customertypecode'/>
        <attribute name='customertypecodename'/>
        <attribute name='defaultpricelevelid'/>
        <attribute name='defaultpricelevelidname'/>
        <attribute name='description'/>
        <attribute name='donotbulkemail'/>
        <attribute name='donotbulkemailname'/>
        <attribute name='donotbulkpostalmail'/>
        <attribute name='donotbulkpostalmailname'/>
        <attribute name='donotemail'/>
        <attribute name='donotemailname'/>
        <attribute name='donotfax'/>
        <attribute name='donotfaxname'/>
        <attribute name='donotphone'/>
        <attribute name='donotphonename'/>
        <attribute name='donotpostalmail'/>
        <attribute name='donotpostalmailname'/>
        <attribute name='donotsendmarketingmaterialname'/>
        <attribute name='donotsendmm'/>
        <attribute name='emailaddress1'/>
        <attribute name='emailaddress2'/>
        <attribute name='emailaddress3'/>
        <attribute name='entityimage'/>
        <attribute name='entityimage_timestamp'/>
        <attribute name='entityimage_url'/>
        <attribute name='entityimageid'/>
        <attribute name='exchangerate'/>
        <attribute name='fax'/>
        <attribute name='ftpsiteurl'/>
        <attribute name='hoovers_companyid'/>
        <attribute name='hoovers_hooversupdatescheduled'/>
        <attribute name='hoovers_hooversupdatescheduledname'/>
        <attribute name='hoovers_linkedtohoovers'/>
        <attribute name='hoovers_linkedtohooversname'/>
        <attribute name='importsequencenumber'/>
        <attribute name='industrycode'/>
        <attribute name='industrycodename'/>
        <attribute name='isprivatename'/>
        <attribute name='lastonholdtime'/>
        <attribute name='lastusedincampaign'/>
        <attribute name='marketcap'/>
        <attribute name='marketcap_base'/>
        <attribute name='masteraccountidname'/>
        <attribute name='masteraccountidyominame'/>
        <attribute name='masterid'/>
        <attribute name='merged'/>
        <attribute name='mergedname'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedby'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedbyexternalparty'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedbyexternalpartyname'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedbyexternalpartyyominame'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedbyname'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedbyyominame'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedon'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedonbehalfby'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedonbehalfbyname'/>
        <attribute name='modifiedonbehalfbyyominame'/>
        <attribute name='msa_managingpartnerid'/>
        <attribute name='msa_managingpartneridname'/>
        <attribute name='msa_managingpartneridyominame'/>
        <attribute name='name'/>
        <attribute name='numberofemployees'/>
        <attribute name='onholdtime'/>
        <attribute name='opendeals'/>
        <attribute name='opendeals_date'/>
        <attribute name='opendeals_state'/>
        <attribute name='openrevenue'/>
        <attribute name='openrevenue_base'/>
        <attribute name='openrevenue_date'/>
        <attribute name='openrevenue_state'/>
        <attribute name='originatingleadid'/>
        <attribute name='originatingleadidname'/>
        <attribute name='originatingleadidyominame'/>
        <attribute name='overriddencreatedon'/>
        <attribute name='ownerid'/>
        <attribute name='owneridname'/>
        <attribute name='owneridtype'/>
        <attribute name='owneridyominame'/>
        <attribute name='ownershipcode'/>
        <attribute name='ownershipcodename'/>
        <attribute name='owningbusinessunit'/>
        <attribute name='owningteam'/>
        <attribute name='owninguser'/>
        <attribute name='parentaccountid'/>
        <attribute name='parentaccountidname'/>
        <attribute name='parentaccountidyominame'/>
        <attribute name='participatesinworkflow'/>
        <attribute name='participatesinworkflowname'/>
        <attribute name='paymenttermscode'/>
        <attribute name='paymenttermscodename'/>
        <attribute name='preferredappointmentdaycode'/>
        <attribute name='preferredappointmentdaycodename'/>
        <attribute name='preferredappointmenttimecode'/>
        <attribute name='preferredappointmenttimecodename'/>
        <attribute name='preferredcontactmethodcode'/>
        <attribute name='preferredcontactmethodcodename'/>
        <attribute name='preferredequipmentid'/>
        <attribute name='preferredequipmentidname'/>
        <attribute name='preferredserviceid'/>
        <attribute name='preferredserviceidname'/>
        <attribute name='preferredsystemuserid'/>
        <attribute name='preferredsystemuseridname'/>
        <attribute name='preferredsystemuseridyominame'/>
        <attribute name='primarycontactid'/>
        <attribute name='primarycontactidname'/>
        <attribute name='primarycontactidyominame'/>
        <attribute name='primarysatoriid'/>
        <attribute name='primarytwitterid'/>
        <attribute name='processid'/>
        <attribute name='revenue'/>
        <attribute name='revenue_base'/>
        <attribute name='sharesoutstanding'/>
        <attribute name='shippingmethodcode'/>
        <attribute name='shippingmethodcodename'/>
        <attribute name='sic'/>
        <attribute name='slaid'/>
        <attribute name='slainvokedid'/>
        <attribute name='slainvokedidname'/>
        <attribute name='slaname'/>
        <attribute name='stageid'/>
        <attribute name='statecode'/>
        <attribute name='statecodename'/>
        <attribute name='statuscode'/>
        <attribute name='statuscodename'/>
        <attribute name='stockexchange'/>
        <attribute name='telephone1'/>
        <attribute name='telephone2'/>
        <attribute name='telephone3'/>
        <attribute name='territorycode'/>
        <attribute name='territorycodename'/>
        <attribute name='territoryid'/>
        <attribute name='territoryidname'/>
        <attribute name='tickersymbol'/>
        <attribute name='timezoneruleversionnumber'/>
        <attribute name='transactioncurrencyid'/>
        <attribute name='transactioncurrencyidname'/>
        <attribute name='traversedpath'/>
        <attribute name='utcconversiontimezonecode'/>
        <attribute name='versionnumber'/>
        <attribute name='websiteurl'/>
        <attribute name='yominame'/>
        <filter>
            <condition attribute='modifiedon' operator='gt' value='@[User::LastRunDate]' />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you please try to include the `ownerid` field in your query and check to see if you can get value for the `owneridtype` field?

Note that in order to read from those virtual fields (such as lookup name or OptionSet name fields), you must include their supporting/dependent fields (the lookup fields or OptionSet fields).

If you have any other questions, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, yes owneridname and ownerid are in the fetch query already, and the ownerid data definitely makes it to the final table. I put a data viewer directly after the kingsway component and only saw nulls for all the type fields.

Comment: Yep, I added the query to the original question.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the query. Your query looks good for us, and we did some quick tests on our end, we were able to get the correct value of `owneridtype` field using the similar query. Can you please try to click the **Refresh CRM Metadata** button on the CRM Source component to see if it helps? Have you tried to choose the **Entity** as the **Source Type** and check to see if you can get values for this field?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I was able to get the codeName and lookUp through Entity as a data source. This does not work directly with fetchXml.

Comment: This isn't necessarily accurate. For the issue that OP described, I don't think there is a need to do such lookup, which is too cumbersome to implement. You just need to include the underlying base field in the query, which should take care of the issue by returning those additional fields, as suggested by our team previously.